# Call a JSON responding API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new in javascript (and jquery), and I want to call an api like this:

```
{"GOOGL":{"PRICE":950.123},"TSLA":{"PRICE":345.67}}
```

I tried with my code but it didn't work:

```
var list = ["GOOGL","TSLA"];


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('api.json', function(data) {
        for (var i in list) {
                console.log(data.list[i].PRICE);
        };
    });
});
```

I got an error like this : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `data[list[i]].PRICE`.

Comment: It means `data.list` is undefined, try to check what what is the contents of `data` by `console.log(data)`

Comment: @nnnnnn in list var there is no price `var list = ["GOOGL","TSLA"];` OP is not very clear he has `{"GOOGL":{"PRICE":950.123},"TSLA":{"PRICE":345.67}}` but in the loop he is using `list`

Comment: @guradio - There's no `PRICE` in `list`, but there is a `PRICE` in `data[list[i]]`. That is, for each item in `list`, its price could be retrieved from `data`. (Though of course this still risks an "undefined" error if `list` includes items that aren't in `data`.)

Comment: how do you think the indexes of list, (which is what `i` will be, `0, 1`) is related to the content of data.list? I think you meant `for (i of list)` so i is `"GOOGL"` then `"TSLA"`

Comment: @nnnnnn, it works like charm, thank you so much!

Comment: @nnnnnn ah i see it now.. new things to learn everyday :) happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) mentioned in the comments, you could do:

```
console.log(data[list[i]].PRICE);
```

To explain:

`list[i]` will return the value stored in `list` at index `i` (like `GOOGL` and `TSLA`).

The values stored in `data` (`{"GOOGL":{"PRICE":950.123},"TSLA":{"PRICE":345.67}}`) seem to use the values of `list[i]` (`GOOGL` and `TSLA`) as keys.

This means that doing `data["GOOGL"]` (with `data[list[i]]`) will get you `{"PRICE":950.123}`.

Then taking it another step `data["GOOGL"].PRICE` (with `data[list[i]].PRICE`) would get you `950.123`.

Whereas `console.log(data.list[i].PRICE);` doesn't work because it's looking for the `list` property (which doesn't exist) in the `data` object.

In that case, you will see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` when `i` is zero because `data.list` returns undefined (and the code is trying to get property `0` from it).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i in list) { 
    console.log(data[list[i]].PRICE); 
};
```

Its not possible to use variable names to access the properties of an object using dot operator.

So you gotta use the array notation..

Answer (score 0):

@kevin: You can't access object keys with dot operator for that you have to pass that key inside the hash like "data[list[i]].PRICE"